# .Museum Domain Name Registrar

Tags: domains

Anyone know of a reputable domain name company which deals in .museum domain names?

Previously we had used DomainBank without much issue. DomainBank was bought by Dotster and am having nothing but trouble since the switch. Currently the website has been down for two days and it is a MAJOR issue.

I know .museum is a seldom used domain name but I really need to switch to a reputable company. GoDaddy doesn't work with them unfortunately. Anyone know of a good company that does?

Comment: Note that in 2017/2018 the registry has changed and hence the registrars. See http://domainincite.com/22046-museum-soon-could-be-open-to-all-no-haters-please and https://www.afnic.fr/en/about-afnic/news/general-news/10947/show/afnic-and-muse-doma-to-give-a-fresh-boost-to-museum.html

Answer (score 3):

[Here's the list](http://about.museum/registrars/) of registrars the TLD manager authorizes to register .museum domain names. Anyone else is probably a reseller, at some level. That of course assumes the about.museum site is kept up to date.

You're not exactly specific about what your "nothing but trouble" entails, but beyond the above any recommendations aren't really going to be much more than anecdata, so this is as far as we can go. (For example, you seem to cite GoDaddy as a presumably-acceptable alternative if they'd support the TLD, but there are *plenty* of people who hate them, so…)

Comment: Yea none of those are in the U.S., as far as nothing but trouble, Dotster accidentally deleted my domain record in a server migration and my institutions website has been down going on 3 days. The customer support is pretty much non-existent and my job is probably in great jeopardy. Godaddy I wouldn't recommend for hosting or email but have never had a problem with a domain name and I can get them on the phone and get to the right people if need be. I'm beyopnd frusterated with dotster, never had a problem with domainbank, as soon as they get bought by dotster MAJOR issues

Comment: Why is it relevant where the registrar is located?

Comment: Because I'm an American and I buy American. But seriously, I don't want to have to call Germany to talk to the people who have my domain in case there's an issue like the one I just had. Also, I don't know of any legal issue that might occur and it's my institutions domain name. Not mine.